# Showing a subfield is fixed under complex conjugation

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose we let $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the complex conjugate map, and we have a subfield $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with $L/\mathbb{Q}$ a finite Galois extension.

I want to show that $\sigma(L)=L$

I was wondering whether it is necessary (or even possible) to use the Fundamental theorem of Galois Theory to answer this, saying as $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois that as a result we have $\sigma(L)=L$ for any $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

The problem is I am not actually sure if $\sigma$ is in this group, as I feel I would need to know that the complex conjugate of any element of $L$ was also in $L$ to ensure that it is actually an automorphism, and if this is the case wouldn't it just follow directly anyway that $\sigma(L)=L$.

Sorry if this comes across incoherent I am just pretty confused, help appreciated as always :)

Comment: Hint: Let $z\in L$ be arbitrary. Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. Answer the following two questions: 1) Why is $\sigma(z)$ also a zero of $m(x)$? 2) Why does this imply that $\sigma(z)$ is an element of $L$?

Comment: UsernameInvalid: Props (+1) for realizing that there is a problem in applying the result that you mentioned. A more general result at play here reads: *If $L/K$ is Galois, $L\subseteq M$, and $\sigma$ is a $K$-automorphism of $M$, then $\sigma(L)=L$*

Comment: Thank you for the replies! So if I take $z \in L$ and let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then as $z$ is a root of $m(x)$ I can show that the conjugate is also a root (by properties of the conjugate function with sums and powers etc). Then suppose that this conjugate $\sigma(L) \notin L$, then this would mean that the extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ was not normal, and hence not Galois forming a contradiction, so $\sigma(L)$ must be in $L$. I think this should work but let me know if theres something wrong with this :)

Comment: Correct! You could flesh that argument out  and post it as an answer. That way you will get some feedback on evenetual lingering unclear points. And then you can mark the question as answered :-)